# How to make responsive Android application which can be use in every screen mobile?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, user-interface

I have created an Android application.

When I run my application in Mobile Phone it works very well, but when I run in another mobile phone the layout of the application is changed buttons are moved, text views are moved in a different position. I tested on every pixel device which is listed in Device for Preview section in Android Studio. So how can I design which is fit for every device?

I designed all the layouts in the constraint layout and I created every constraint of buttons, edit text box and every layout item.

[Form 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmaSz.png)  [Form 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNa9q.png)  Both have used the same screen size and same resolution also

[Form 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/651k6.png)  [Form 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rijJY.png)

Can anyone help me, please?

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/leadtextview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:text="Lead Creation Form"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/emailaddress"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.95" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/emailaddress"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="448dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.476" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/company_name"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="384dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Comapny name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.581" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mobile"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="284dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Mobile"
    android:inputType="phone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.596" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/address"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="144dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Address"
    android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.579" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/country"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.538" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/state"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.133"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/country"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.544" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/city"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.595" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.13"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/city"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.595" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/pincode"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Pin Code"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.68" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/registration_button"
    android:layout_width="152dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:text="Registration"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.964" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/lead_decription"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
    android:hint="Description"
    android:paddingStart="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pincode"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.17" />
```

Comment: Can you post you layout code? It seems that the constraints are not set properly, otherwise every device should give you the same outcome

Comment: Yes, I am posting, but Is Constraint layout fit for every device?

Comment: Yes, constraint layout is part of teh support libraries to offer backwards compatibility

Comment: The problem is you constrain most of your views to the parent, whereas you should be adding relative constraints between the views themselves. If you have A vertical form like this, and you want to have textViews and EditTexts appear one after the other, try adding  app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="name_of_the_viewBelow" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="name_of_the_view_above" accordingly

Comment: also have a look at chains: https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html

Comment: I am facing the same problem after creating constraint according to your suggestion. I create the top and bottom constraint according to the top and bottom view but give responsive output.

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned also, that If you do this you don't need the horizontal/vertical bias, so you can get rid of those as well.

Comment: also your margins would need readjustments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is you constrain most of your views to the parent, whereas you should be adding relative constraints between the views themselves. If you have A vertical form like this, and you want to have textViews and EditTexts appear one after the other, try adding app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="name_of_the_viewBelow" app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="name_of_the_view_above" accordingly
>
> sorry I should have mentioned also, that If you do this you don't need the horizontal/vertical bias, so you can get rid of those as well.
>
> also your margins would need readjustments

An example to my comments above would be the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/leadtextview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Lead Creation Form"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/emailaddress"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/leadtextview" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailaddress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/company_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/company_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Comapny name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/mobile"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/emailaddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mobile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Mobile"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/address"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/company_name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"

        android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Address"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/country"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mobile" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/country"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/city"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/state"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/address" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/state"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/country"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/country"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/country" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/city"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/pincode"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/status"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/country" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/city"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/city"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/city" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pincode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Pin Code"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/lead_decription"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/city" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/registration_button"
        android:layout_width="152dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:text="Registration"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lead_decription" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lead_decription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
        android:hint="Description"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/registration_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pincode" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This code should produce a uniform layout in different devices.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me, please is there necessary to create every constraint of every field ?

Comment: and can you tell me how you fix it, please ?

Comment: @TARUNSHARMA it's not always necessary to add all constraint types to all views, but that is down to what you need. For example, if you want to centre a view both horizontally and vertically in your screen you add all constraints (start, end, top, bottom) and have them constraint with "parent". But if you want your view to remain at the top of the screen, you constraint the top to parent and don't use the bottom constraint. The combinations are endless depending on what you want to achieve. I suggest you check Medium for relevant tutorials, or the android developers channel on youtube

Comment: @TARUNSHARMA what's confusing you specifically regarding the top 4 EditTexts?

Comment: Thank you, Sir, confusion is top 4 textboxes are fixed how did you fix it, via chain or another way?

Comment: @TARUNSHARMA I did use vertical chains for most of the views.

Comment: Finally, I understand the constraint layout thank you so much, sir :)

Comment: @TARUNSHARMA Glad I could help.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the use ConstraintLayout, check this : https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes

Comment: link-only answers are always bad answers.

Comment: also the user already claims to have designed their layouts with ConstraintLayout